# Merge n objects from n arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects and I want to create a new array of objects where every object is a merged version from previous two objects, for example:

```
const one = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Two' }
]

const two = [
  { status: 'Open' },
  { status: 'Close' }
]
```

From above arrays I'll expect:

```
const result = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One', status: 'Open' },
  { id: 1, title: 'Two', status: 'Close' }
]
```

The question here is I don't know how to create a function that actually can receive n arrays of objects and creates the new one, for example if I wanna to merge a third array:

```
const three = [
  { items: 10 },
  { items: 2 }
]
```

I'll expected the following array:

```
const result = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One', status: 'Open', items: 10 },
  { id: 1, title: 'Two', status: 'Close', items: 2 }
]
```

I think that actually I can create a function that receive a spread but I don't know how to merged every object from every array recived into the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Array.reduce" or "Array.map" to achieve this like below

```js
const one = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Two' }
]

const two = [
  { status: 'Open' },
  { status: 'Close' }
]

const three = [
  { items: 10 },
  { items: 2 }
]

// using REDUCE
function mergeArrays1(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].reduce((a, d, i) => a.concat(Object.assign(...arrays.map(d => d[i]))), [])
}

// Using Map
function mergeArrays2(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].map((d, i) => Object.assign(...arrays.map(d => d[i])))
}

console.log(mergeArrays1([one, two, three]))
console.log(mergeArrays2([one, two, three]))
```

Comment: It seems that reduce solution is slightly faster

Comment: Great! You can then go ahead with Reduce solution. Though, I think difference would be hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in every array as an argument, then use `.map` on one of them to `Object.assign` every item in the new array:

```js
const merge = (...arrs) => arrs[0].map((_, i) => (
  //                   Extract the [i]th item from every array:
  Object.assign({}, ...arrs.map(arr => arr[i]))
));

const one = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Two' }
];
const two = [
  { status: 'Open' },
  { status: 'Close' }
];
const three = [
  { items: 10 },
  { items: 2 }
];

console.log(merge(one, two));
console.log(merge(one, two, three));
```

Of course, this depends on every array having the same number of elements.

Comment: Hi, I have added an answer for both Reduce and Map, and later realised your Map solution already exists(which is same as mine).. and I didn't see that earlier. So pls dnt mind..

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** if you know the number of arrays you'll have to merge.

Alternatively, you can also use Lodash's **[`merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge)** for this. That way you can pass any number of arrays as an argument.

Try this:

```js
const one = [
  { id: 1, title: 'One' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Two' }
];

const two = [
  { status: 'Open' },
  { status: 'Close' }
];

const three = [
  { items: 10 },
  { items: 2 }
];

// Normal Merge
function merge(one, two, three) {
  return one.map(
    (item, index) => ({
      ...item,
      ...two[index],
      ...three[index]
    })
  );
}

// Lodash Merge
function mergeWithLodash(...arrays) {
  return _.merge(...arrays);
}

console.log(merge(one, two, three));

console.log('merged with lodash: ', mergeWithLodash(one, two, three));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not take into account the possibility of an unknown amount of arrays that need to be merged.